# Overlay between Tikz and text

Tags: tikz-pgf, text

My generated code in latex here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\myblue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mygray}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
\newcommand{\myrule}{\color{blue}\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]

\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,opacity=0.03] at (current page.north west)
  {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=8cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}};

\node[anchor=west,text=gray,font=\footnotesize] at (-1.9,0.8) {\today};
\node[anchor=north west,yshift=5mm] at (9,1) 
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    Name
   
\node[anchor=west,text=black,font=\large] at (-2.2,-1.2) {University of};  



\end{tikzpicture}


aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaadffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffablEQ   FQBEBFBEKLQBLBQLUEFBABDFJkbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

\end{document}
```

Then the text should be under the Tikz, so which commands should I use? Any helps is appreciated !!!

[image]

Comment: A `tikzpicture` consume space whenever you don't say `overlay, remember picture`. In this case you need to introduce a desired vertical space before the text. Just try it. Comment out the `tikzpicture` and will see how the text is at the "correct" position. Or comment `overlay` and will see how the text is below the tikzpicture.

Comment: yes, thank you a lot, I fixed it !! @Ignasi